# Ready solution for converting raw collections to generic

Tags: java, apache, collections, guava, apache-commons

I wonder if there is ready solution, that converts raw collection (List, Set etc.) to generic collection (List, Set etc.). I've wrote my own bicycle for it:

```
public <T> List<T> filterInstancesOfClass(List list, Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> generifiedList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object o : list) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(o)) {
            generifiedList.add(clazz.cast(o));
        }
    }
    return generifiedList;
}
```

But I'm sure, that there should be a ready solution somewhere in popular libraries, that work with collections (Apache, Guava). Do you know one?

UPD. Unfortunately I can't use Java 8 in my case, so I'm looking for a ready solution outside JDK.

Comment: This would be more elegant using the Streams API.  It doesn't convert anything but it does filter.

Comment: Why do you need this logic if it's just for "typing"? You could just cast. The code in the loop does nothing except check that `clazz` is compatible with each entry in the collection. But that's more than "type conversion"

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something very short, you could use [jOOλ](https://github.com/jooq/jool)'s [Seq.ofType()](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#ofType-java.lang.Class-) like that:

```
Seq.seq(list).ofType(clazz).toList()
```

---

*EDIT*: Well, when on JDK 6 or JDK 7, you can use [Guava 20.0](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReleaseHistory) and its [`Iterables.filter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Class-) method like this:

```
public <T> List<T> filterInstancesOfClass(List<?> list, Class<T> clazz) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(list, clazz));
}
```

In case you don't need your returned `List`s to me mutable, you can replace [`Lists.newArrayList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList-java.lang.Iterable-) with [`ImmutableList.copyOf`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf-java.lang.Iterable-).

Answer (score 3):

There is no ready-to-go solution, but you can do the same thing in one line like this:

```
public <T> List<T> filterInstancesOfClass(List<?> list, Class<T> clazz) {
    return list.stream().filter(p -> clazz.isInstance(p)).map(p -> clazz.cast(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This is useful to make immediately clear that your method is filtering on compatible objects.